# Should I flag duplicate comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

For some reason, a new user post identical comments three times in a row.

When I want to flag it, I don't find the reason "duplicate comments" in the list. I flagged it, choose "Others" as reason and put "duplicate comments" in it.

So, should I flag duplicate comments like this? I think I should, but I just want to be sure.

btw, the offending comments is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064161/1583566

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should. In other words, It's sometimes your job to flag such comments (since you're also a community member). But of course, It could be flagged as "obsolete" (which is no longer in use). Manual flagging (other) could also be done. Users

The comments are all identical and could be deleted. I think the user was somewhat raged in commenting. [The first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064109/i-want-to-make-a-method-that-subtracts-25-from-an-my-hp-value-but-there-is-an-i/14064161#comment19439904_14064161) would be useful. The other comments could be flagged indeed.